# How to dequeue styles from a different file than the theme's functions.php?

Tags: css, wordpress, hook

The WP standard CSS dequeue code below works if contained in the theme's `functions.php`. But if contained in another file instead, say `my_theme/some_folder/some_template_file.php` then it doesn't work (that is, stylesheet doesn't get dequeued any more). Why? Is there any workaround other than including the code in `my_theme/functions.php` (which for off-topic reasons I can't do)?

```
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'dequeue_iw_theme_styles', 100);
function dequeue_iw_theme_styles() {
  wp_dequeue_style('iw');
}
```

Just in case, the stylesheet in question is called from `my_theme/functions.php` this way:

```
wp_enqueue_style('iw', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/iw.css', array(), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/iw.css'));
```

Comment: the other way is to create a plugin and put the code in plugin file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know if there exists some other way than creating a plugin or writing a child theme for that.

Writing a plugin would not be ideal for such a small, theme-specific task; but you can always write a child-theme to override specific things in your theme.

In child theme's `functions.php`, you can add the code for de-registering or de-queue-ing the scripts you want. This way, you would avoid touching the original `functions.php` of your theme, and it is actually the best practice to add customization to WordPress themes.

#### References

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
- https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet

Hope it was helpful. Cheers!